# Diferencia entre HMAC y funciones hash

Tags: funciones, seguridad, criptografía, sha1

No me ha quedado muy clara la diferencia entre HMAC y las funciones hash como SHA. Creo que la principal diferencia está en que HMAC usa una clave y usa una función hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un HMAC es un hash con un valor secreto, de forma que el HMAC calculado sólo puede haber sido generado por quien la conoce.

Se puede añadir al principio o al final.

Por ejemplo, si hago un HMAC con la contraseña "pepe" del texto "En un Lugar de La Mancha" el resultado, que es un hash, sólo lo puedo haber calculado yo. Haría el hash de "pepeEn un Lugar de La Mancha" (obviamente este es un ejemplo burdo)

Se usa para añadir a la integridad (el texto original no ha cambiado) el no repudio de emisor (sólo yo lo pude calcular)

Es, en cierto modo, una firma electrónica (pero sin claves asimétricas)